# Codeigniter: how to create custom active record methods? like methods in the core, DB_active_rec.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

The main requirement is: I want to create a reusable component or function that would allow me to do database queries and specify a database(group), maybe in its argument.

> but for now, maybe a simple one like the following would be enough:
>
> `$this->db->get_all_by_specific_db('tablename',$config['group1']);`
>
> //where $config['group1'] is the database configuration of the specific database where I want to get my data with the table specified. I'm saying "specific database", since I used many database as if it's an entity, and it could grow more in number to scale

do you have any suggestion to meet this requirement? workarounds? etc. Or maybe there is already an existing api or documentation(specifically in DB_active_rec.php) that codeigniter team did but I just missed to find it. Any suggestions, links, about tutorial or other resources (maybe further study on php designing and OOP stuffs to meet this would be highly appreciated.

PS: Im using pyrocms, but I believe php or codeigniter implementations may also address this one.

Comment: i would say, move away from codeigniter because it is very tightly coupled and if you make one changes here, some bugs may appear elsewhere.... Laravel does a pretty good job in this. Moreover, codeigniter's future is uncertain as of now. may be it is time to try another framework?

Comment: Have you read [the user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) regarding manually connecting to databases and connecting to multiple databases?

Comment: @koala_dev- yes, actually I can already connect to multiple databases. But it turns out that it does not come in handy, and its too wordy. that's how I have come up and dreamed to shorten it as clean as just: $this->db->get_all_by_specific_db('tablename',$config['group1']);